# Compare array of keys against predefined array - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, rspec, cucumber

I would like to compare the keys I get back in a JSON response for all results against a pre defined array of keys.

So I have this set of keys

```
def key_array
 ["key1", "key2", "key3"] 
end
```

My response from an api call is returned in this format (array of hashes) outputted from `@response`

```
{"0"=>
  {"key1"=>"value1",
   "key2"=>"value2",
   "key3"=>"value3"},
 "1"=>
   {"key1"=>"value1",
    "key2"=>"value2",
    "key3"=>"value3"},
 "2"=>
   {"key1"=>"value1",
    "key2"=>"value2",
    "key3"=>"value3"},
 "Status"=>"100"}
}
```

When I do `@response.keys` I get

```
["0", "1", "2"]
```

I can access each set of keys via its index individually with `@response["0"].keys`, for example will return

```
  ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
```

What I would like to do with the rspec matchers is check that every returned result from the api call has the keys set in `key_array`

At the moment

```
expect(@response.keys).to match_array(key_array)
```

is matching the array of indexes against the `key_array` I have stored. How do I access the keys from within each index?

Comment: thanks to all those that answered, I have just noticed within my response is status => 100 which is causing issues with iteration.is there anyway to remove this from the response before i start going through the data?

Comment: Pls see update on my answer: status (actually, any non-integer-like key) handled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@response.each_value do |value|
  expect(value.keys).to match_array(key_array)
end
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me learn about the `each_value` method. From there I tried `each_key` and learned that works too! Noice! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
required_keys = %w{key1 key2 key3}
@response.each do |key, hash|
  next if (key == "Status")
  expect(hash).to include(*required_keys)
end
```

You can add an optional message to see which index any failure occured on:

```
@response.each do |key, hash|
  next if (key == "Status")
  expect(hash).to include(*required_keys), "Failed at #{key}"
end
```

The `next` check can be turned into a regular-expression check, in case you've got other non-numeric keys that you want to ignore e.g.

```
next if /\D/.match(key) # the \D matches non-digits
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want call expect method only once, you can do

```
expect( @response.values.map{|h| h.keys.sort}.uniq ).to eq([%w(key1 key2 key3)])
```

however it is rather ugly approach

Answer (score 1):

I would firstly harvest incompletes:

```
incompletes = @response.reduce([]) { |memo, kv| 
  (key_array - kv.last.keys).empty? ? memo : memo << kv.first 
}
```

And then do checks:

```
expect(incompletes).to match_array([])
```

Whether you only need to check:

```
incompletes = @response.reject { |*kv| (key_array - kv.last.keys).empty? }
expect(incompletes).to match_array([])
```

This former approach makes it easy to collect any desired information about wrong entries, since you are free to put anything valuable in the resulting array. Hope it helps.

**UPD** With status:

```
incompletes = @response.reject { |k,v| 
# ⇓⇓ is k integer? ⇓⇓  or  ⇓⇓ are valid keys all presented? ⇓⇓
   k.to_i.to_s != k    ||      (key_array - v.keys).empty? 
}
expect(incompletes).to match_array([])
```

Comment: thanks, i just found this works aswell `@response.delete_if { |k| ["Status"].include? k }`

Comment: Tests are generally not supposed to modify values. `#delete_if` __modifies hash inplace__.

Comment: I do like your answer and sure it works, though I am not an expert on ternary operators and i am having trouble reading what your answer is doing, i get parts of it but not all.. is there anyway of simplifying this please? apologies

Comment: The last variant (without ternaries) does select from a `@response` all those entries, having neither 'Status' key nor all the required fields. As soon as this array is empty, everything is ok.